# Multiple iPhone OS devices attached to one Mac -- how to select for build

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, device

I have an iPod touch with OS 2.2.1 and an iPhone 3GS with OS 3.0 both attached to my Mac. They both show up in Xcode Organizer. I now would like to be able to select which one of them an application gets installed on when running it from Xcode during testing. Is there any way at all to do this (except unplugging one of the devices, of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which version of XCode you're running there should be an Overview pop-up in the main window (above Groups & Files list) that allows you to pick which device you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t notice that before. Not seeing the forest for the trees. Duh :)